# Getting affected row in trigger

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a simple trigger to track changes in table. Now, I'm in the situation where I need the affected row, when the trigger is fired.

Let's say there is a trigger called "blah" with AFTER DELETE. The trigger does some operation, unimportant stuff. For my purposes, I need the deleted row. How do I get it? Is there some equivalent to `(object sender, EventArgs e)` like in C#?

Comment: Word of advice: the trigger is executing once per **batch** of updates or deletes - that means, the  `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables available in your trigger code **might contain multiple** rows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `SELECT * FROM deleted`. Deleted is a special "table" that exists within the context of the trigger that contains the rows that were deleted.

You can learn more about these special tables from MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inside your trigger you can just do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM deleted
```

Inside the trigger there will be a special table called deleted (or inserted for insert and update triggers.

Comment: @System.Data: I'll add that can DELETED etc can contain 0 to many rows: you have to allow for multiple row DML. And +1